# How to add column to FoxPro file using DAO

Tags: vb6, dao, foxpro

I need to add some columns to a FoxPro 2.6 DBF file using DAO in VB6.

If the data were in an .MDB file, I know this would work. Here is a code snippet which I use for .MDB:

```
Set tdfCoParms = mDBParms.TableDefs(CoParms)
tdfCoParms.Fields.Append tdfCoParms.CreateField("CoName", dbText, 30)
```

Am unsure if this works for FoxPro. (I have not tried)

Is this possible? There is a possible alternative - which I know would work, but which is not so convenient - by starting with an empty table of the correct structure, then copying across the records from the existing populated file, using INSERT of a SELECT from this.

Comment: This or `"ALTER TABLE [" & CoParms & "] ADD COLUMN [" & CoName & "] VARCHAR(30)"`

Comment: Thanks wqw, but this gives error 3282 "Operation not supported on a table that contains data."

I resolved this using the possible alternative I described - see details below.

Comment: Missed the time-out for editing the previous comment -see my solution below, as I cannot see how to format the code here.

Comment: @wqw you were right! Looking at this problem again, I now have an easy solution based on your suggestion. I cannot see how to add the code here so am entering it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @wqw, as your solution certainly works.

This was my first alternative, which worked:

1. Create an empty file/table with the desired columns.
2. Copy this file to "test.dbf".
3. Insert records from the populated data file "link" into this.

```
    Dim dbsWork As Database
    Dim qrd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim szSqlString As String

    Set dbsWork = OpenDatabase(szWorkDir, False, False, "FoxPro 2.5")
    Dim szFieldList As String
    szFieldList = "field1, field2, field3"
    szSqlString = "INSERT INTO test SELECT " & szFieldList & " FROM link"
    Set qrd = dbsWork.CreateQueryDef("", szSqlString)
    qrd.Execute

    Set qrd = Nothing
    Set dbsWork = Nothing
```

But the following based on @wqw's suggestion is much better, as no predefined file is required

```
Private Sub Test1()

    Dim dbsWork As Database
    Dim qrd As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim szSqlString As String

    Set dbsWork = OpenDatabase(MyDataBasPath, False, False, "FoxPro 2.5")
    Dim szFieldList As String
    szSqlString = "ALTER TABLE work.dbf ADD COLUMN fred VARCHAR(30)"
    Set qrd = dbsWork.CreateQueryDef("", szSqlString)
    qrd.Execute

    Set qrd = Nothing
    Set dbsWork = Nothing

End Sub
```